# Drawing selection custom selection box using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, symbology

I have some code that I'm using to selecting features in a certain extent. I already rigged the tool properly, so it selected the objects as needed, but I want to draw interactively the selection box the user is making.

I'm using `IScreenDisplay.DrawRectangle` method, but it pollutes the screen with many small rectangles. Is there a way to clear up the old drawings in the screen?

This Draw method is being called from a mouse move event. Any ideas?

Here are two methods I'm using to do the dirty work:

```
public override void OnMouseMove(int button, int shift, int x, int y)
{
    if (button != 1)
        return;

    if (!_IsSelectOperation)
        return;

    endPoint = focusScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(x, y);
    envelope.PutCoords(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, endPoint.X, endPoint.Y);
    DrawEnvelope(envelope, BuildSelectionSymbol(), focusScreenDisplay);
}

private void DrawEnvelope(IEnvelope envelope, ISymbol symbol, IScreenDisplay screenDisplay)
{
    screenDisplay.StartDrawing(screenDisplay.WindowDC, 0);
    screenDisplay.SetSymbol(symbol);
    screenDisplay.DrawRectangle(envelope);
    screenDisplay.FinishDrawing();
}
```

Here is the code for `BuildSelectionSymbol`:

```
private ISymbol BuildSelectionSymbol()
{
    IColor fillColor = new RgbColorClass();
    fillColor.Transparency = 0;

    IRgbColor outlineColor = new RgbColorClass();
    outlineColor.Red = 0;
    outlineColor.Green = 0;
    outlineColor.Blue = 0;

    ISimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbolClass();
    lineSymbol.Color = outlineColor as IColor;
    lineSymbol.Width = 1;
    lineSymbol.Style = esriSimpleLineStyle.esriSLSDash;

    ISimpleFillSymbol fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbolClass();
    fillSymbol.Color = fillColor;
    fillSymbol.Outline = lineSymbol;
    fillSymbol.Style = esriSimpleFillStyle.esriSFSHollow;

    ISymbol symbol = fillSymbol as ISymbol;
    symbol.ROP2 = esriRasterOpCode.esriROPNOP;

    return symbol;
}
```

---

I already have the answer for this. I was using a normal envelope. The deal is that ESRI already has something to handle that for you and it's contained in INewEnvelopeFeedback class.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Display_feedback/000100000m9s000000/

Actually, this interface got me where the code snippet in the question was. It stills draws all the rectangles, but I still need a way to clean them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It stills draws all the rectangles,
>   but I still need a way to clean them.

For the linesymbol, fillsymbol and symbol, set ROP2 = esriRasterOpCode.esriROPNotXOrPen.

Answer (score 1):

I created a MeaureAreaTool using this sample [Sample: Custom subtyped command and tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000394000000) I don't get any problems with the redraw of the Polygon. Mayby you can get any ideas from my code.

```
Private m_polygonFeedback As INewPolygonFeedback
Private m_screenDisplay As IScreenDisplay

Private m_hookHelper As IHookHelper


Public Overrides Sub OnCreate(ByVal hook As Object)
If (m_hookHelper Is Nothing) Then m_hookHelper = New HookHelperClass

If Not hook Is Nothing Then
m_hookHelper.Hook = hook
End If
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub OnClick()
m_screenDisplay = m_hookHelper.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub OnDblClick()
Dim polygon As IPolygon = m_polygonFeedback.Stop()
MsgBox("Area: " & CType(polygon, IArea).Area)
m_polygonFeedback = Nothing
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
If Button = 1 Then
Dim cursorPoint As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint = m_screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y)

If m_polygonFeedback Is Nothing Then
m_polygonFeedback = New NewPolygonFeedbackClass()
m_polygonFeedback.Display = m_screenDisplay

m_polygonFeedback.Start(cursorPoint)
Else
m_polygonFeedback.AddPoint(cursorPoint)
End If

End If
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
If Not m_polygonFeedback Is Nothing Then
Dim cursorPoint As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint = m_screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y)
m_polygonFeedback.MoveTo(cursorPoint)
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public override void OnMouseDown(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
        {
          if (Button == 2)
            {
                **m_activeview.ScreenDisplay.Invalidate(null, true, m_activeview.get_ScreenCacheID(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null));**
            }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info to explain your answer rather than just some code.