# Highlighting selections using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I have a problem you want help:

[image]

In ArcMap 10.2.2

[image]

In my code I want to highlight selections but I can't.

My code:

```cs
void drawPoint(IFeature pfeature)
{
  IRgbColor rgbColor = new RgbColorClass();
  rgbColor.Red = 255;
  rgbColor.Blue = 0;
  rgbColor.Green = 0;

  IMarkerSymbol simpleMarkerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
  simpleMarkerSymbol.Color = rgbColor;// color RED
  simpleMarkerSymbol.Size = 15;
  IMarkerElement markerElement = null;

  markerElement = new MarkerElementClass();
  markerElement.Symbol = simpleMarkerSymbol;
  IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer =
  GeneralVariableMap.mapControl.Map as IGraphicsContainer;
  IElement element = null;
  element = (IElement)markerElement;
  element.Geometry = pfeature.Shape;
  graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);
}
```

Comment: Which selection are you referring to - the cyan or the yellow?

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/drawing-selection-custom-selection-box-arcobjects

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you only have to refresh the map.
Don't know what is `GeneralVariableMap`.
Usually I do sth like this:

```
mxDocument.ActivatedView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, null);
```

Another idea (not tested):

```
void drawPoint(IFeature pfeature)
{
  IRgbColor rgbColor = new RgbColorClass();
  rgbColor.Red = 255;
  rgbColor.Blue = 0;
  rgbColor.Green = 0;

  IMarkerSymbol simpleMarkerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
  simpleMarkerSymbol.Color = rgbColor;// color RED
  simpleMarkerSymbol.Size = 15;

  IElement element = new MarkerElementClass();
  IMarkerElement markerElement =(IMarkerElement)element;

  markerElement.Symbol = simpleMarkerSymbol;
  IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer =
  GeneralVariableMap.mapControl.Map as IGraphicsContainer;

  element.Geometry = pfeature.Shape;
  graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);
}
```

Comment: It does't work!